# How to know when WebView has refreshed due to JavaScript?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

My webView has an HTML page with JavaScript that changes the appearance of the page when button is pressed in the HTML page. I can have the hosting program receive a callback through JavaScript when the button is pressed, and I can change values on the web page side of things.  However, when these callbacks are made, the appearance change of the page has not yet changed:

1. WebViw is loaded and `frameLoadDelegate` is called
2. ??? WebView is rendered and displayed
3. Customer clicks on the button, JavaScript `onClick' calls a JavaScript function which makes appearance changes, and then calls my Objective-C function.
4. Objective-C function checks appearance of WebView
5. ??? WebView is rendered and displayed

In Apple's WebKit framwork, a WebView that has finished loading its resources sends a `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` message to its `frameLoadDelegate`. However, this only means that resources have been loaded, not that rendering is done… How can I detect that the WebView rendering is done? Among all the delegates of `WebView`, I couldn't find one that has the method I would need…